# How to change MS Edge language

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-10-v1703

After Creators update, MS Edge changed its language (menu, settings, etc.) to english. Is there any way to switch it back to my native language? Everything else is OK, language and location settings in the system did not change. Not that it bothers me that much, but I would like to have consistent language across the system like it was before the update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the **WINDOWS** key
2. Enter "Control Panel"
3. Click on "Control Panel"
4. Click on "Clock, Language, and Region"
5. Click on "Language"
6. If you can see your preferred language move it to the top and log out, if it's already on the top move it down, log out, log in and move it up again and then log out.
7. Now Edge should use the right language.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be broken in Edge – I cannot determine where Edge is getting its languge settings from, but it's **not** the Settings or the Control Panel. In the image below you can see the HTTP Accept-Language header being sent conflicts with the OS settings (but *does* match the keyboard).

[image: HTTP Accept-Language header not consistent with OS laguage settings]

Answer (score 0):

Had to edit the registry, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46317829/3890673) ([cross post](https://blog.crusy.net/ms-edge-sprache-aendern/) in German):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International]
"AcceptLanguage"="en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7"
```

Works in Edge 42 here